# Why I can't initialize a class object when declaring it?

Tags: c++, initialization, operator-overloading, variable-declaration

I have overloaded the assignment operator for a particular class and after that I soon found out a problem.

During the declaration of a class object, if I initialize it with another object that already exists,

```
       objectType object1;
       objectType object2 = object1;
```

the program will terminate with a message of program.exe has stopped working during the run.

However, if I separate the declaration and initialization steps,

```
        objectType object1, object2;
        object2 = object1;
```

it will be working fine.

If we can do this with simple data type,

```
        int x = 6;
        int y = x;
```

Why can't we do this with class object? I hope my question is clear and I have tested this with different computers with the same .exe has stopped working result.

Edited:
Here's my code. The class itself is a stack.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    struct nodeType
    {
        int info;
        nodeType *link;
    };

    class objectType
    {
        public:

            const objectType& operator=(const objectType& otherObject)
            {
                if(this != &otherObject)
                {
                    copyObject(otherObject);
                }
                return *this;
            }

            void initialize() //Initialize the stack
            {
                nodeType *temp; 

                while(stackTop != nullptr)
                {
                    temp = stackTop;
                    stackTop = stackTop->link;
                    delete temp;
                }
            }

            objectType(const objectType& otherObject) //Copy constructor
            {
                copyObject(otherObject);
            }

            objectType() //Constructor
            {
                stackTop = nullptr;
            }

            ~objectType() //Destructor
            {
                initialize();
            }

        private:
            nodeType* stackTop;

            //Copy function to implement copy constructor and overload assignment operator
            void copyObject(const objectType& otherObject)
            {
                initialize();

                if(otherObject.stackTop != nullptr)
                {
                    nodeType *current, *last, *newNode;

                    current = otherObject.stackTop;

                    stackTop = new nodeType;
                    stackTop->info = current->info;
                    stackTop->link = nullptr;

                    last = stackTop;
                    current = current->link;

                    while(current != nullptr)
                    {
                        newNode = new nodeType;
                        newNode->info = current->info;
                        newNode->link = nullptr;

                        last->link = newNode;
                        last = newNode;

                        current = current->link;
                    }
                }
            }
    };

    int main()
    {
        objectType object1;
        objectType object2 = object1;
        return 0;
    }
```

After I tested it with debugger, I found out the problem was the destructor. As I know, the destructor is called when the object goes out of scope. Does the object go out of scope in this case?

P.S. Can this code be considered as MCVE now? And yeah reproducing the code really helps me to find out the real root of the problem.

Comment: Seems like your copy constructor may contain errors. The problem is definitely with `objectType`. In principal, there is nothing wrong with `objectType object2 = object1;`.

Comment: Without code there is no way of answering that question. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should show the definition for `objectType`. Also use a debugger to turn "has stopped working" into "segmentation fault in this line of code", which is much more useful.

Comment: That is not a copy ctor, please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Are you aware that your copy constructor only assigns to local variables?

Comment: @Slava Sorry, my fault. I already added the code.

Comment: You didn't provide a MCVE though

Comment: @HolmesQueen Your program doesn't reproduce the problem that you describe on my system: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e91b9b202f58feda

Comment: At a guess `initializeStack` is failing due to uninitialised variables, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eerorika Guys, after reproducing the problem, I think something's wrong with the destructor, but why does it go wrong?

Comment: " but why does it go wrong?" you do not define assignment operator and possible violate the rule of 3/5/0 so thats why you have different behavior in thous 2 cases.

Comment: @Slava When I include the overloaded assignment operator, I still get the same error, I didn't include it because I don't think it's the root of the problem.

Comment: your copy constructor doesn't initialise `stackTop` to null so `initialize` has undefined behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your `objectType` has a broken copy constructor implementation, but a working copy assignment operator.

You can prove to yourself that this is not a feature of classes, by doing it with any other type (e.g. `std::string`).

Unfortunately we cannot tell you **how** it is broken, because we can't see it; fire up your debugger and get cracking!